# Salesforce Shield Decryption When Using API

Tags: soap-api, streaming-api, shield-encryption

Our application supports reading data from salesforce in a batch form and also as a real time sync. We have been using the salesforce [SOAP api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm) and the real time [streaming api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_stream.htm) for the two use cases respectively.

Assuming the salesforce object fields are encrypted using salesforce shield encryption, I would like to know if there are any code changes required for decrypting the data when reading through these api's or is the decryption done transparently by salesforce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shield protects the data at rest (on the Salesforce servers). It has no effect on if the users can view the data in normal situations. The data is automatically encrypted and decrypted in real-time for you.